# how to escape }] character in java?

Tags: java, groovy, escaping

How to escape special character in java?
I need to this special character but not sure how to escpace it.......

```
estDMS__BottlerID__c":""}]"
```

I have tried

```
 String data = "\estDMS__BottlerID__c\"\:\"\"\}\]";
```

it return

```
Exception org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script434.groovy: 28: unexpected char: '\' @ line 28, column 30.
string symbol = ":""\}]";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
String data = "\\estDMS__BottlerID__c\":\"\"}]";
```

You have to escape the first backslash. And you don't need to escape these characters : `:`, `}`, `]`

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use single quotes:

```
 String data = 'estDMS__BottlerID__c":""}]"'
 String data1 = '\\estDMS__BottlerID__c":""}]"'
```